# Адаптивная верстка Flexbox картинки разной ширины и высоты в определенном порядке

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как-нибудь с помощью flexbox используя только один контейнер-обертку, в котором 6 изображений, выставить их так, как на картинке, чтобы потом при адаптивной вертске они выводились в том порядке, в котором идут цифры на них. У меня только есть идеи как это сделать с помощью нескольких контейнеров. Но потом не смогу вывести в нужном порядке. Ведь, если я правильно понимаю, то свойство order работает только в одном контейнере.

Comment: Нельзя. Хочешь одну обертку - используй гриды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 grid-template-areas: "row-1 row-1 row-2" "row-1 row-1 row-2" "row-3 row-5 row-2" "row-4 row-5 row-6";
}

.block {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.block-1 { grid-area: row-1; }
.block-2 { grid-area: row-2; }
.block-3 { grid-area: row-3; }
.block-4 { grid-area: row-4; }
.block-5 { grid-area: row-5; }
.block-6 { grid-area: row-6; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="block block-1">
  <h1>1</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="block block-2">
  <h1>2</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="block block-3">
  <h1>3</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="block block-4">
  <h1>4</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="block block-5">
  <h1>5</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="block block-6">
  <h1>6</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Самое простое на **Grid**'ах.

`grid-template-areas` отвечает за сетку, которую можно задать:

**строка** - `"row-1 row-1 row-2"`

**строка** - `"row-1 row-1 row-2"`

**строка** - `"row-3 row-5 row-2"`

**строка** - `"row-4 row-5 row-6"`

**Я визуально поделил каждый блок на 3 столбца и 4 строки.** И создал некое подобие матрицы.
Дальше я дал имена каждому из блоков и просто построил сетку как на вашей картинке.

upd: можно извращаться и сделать на **flex**'ax но тогда у вас будет не один контейнер и структура вашей верстки будет гораздо больше, нежели воспользоваться тем инструментом, который предназначен для таких целей.